# Find the first vowel of a String that I call by his Getter method?

Tags: java

I have a 3 class program, and I need to know the first vowel in a String.

This String has his getter and setter methods. I tried to use by example:

```
obj.getnameString().charAt(i);
```

where (i) is a value previously obtained. But this throws a `null` value. why?

Comment: Can you attach your code? We won’t be of any help without it.

Comment: Please add your code and clarify. `charAt` doesn't throw a null value or exception. If you mean you're getting a `NullPointerException` then it's from something else bu we cannot tell.

Comment: A program throws **exceptions**, not values. If you mean a `NullPointerException` is thrown from this line it means that either `obj` is `null` or `obj.getnameString()` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say if you don't provide any code, especially to say where the null value comes from. But from how I understand it, you can just iterate through the String and check each char if it's a vowel?

Something like this:

```
String str = obj.getnameString();
char firstVowel;    

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) == "a" || str.charAt(i) == "o" || ...... || str.charAt(i) == "U"){ //pretty sure theres an easier solution for that
        firstVowel = str.charAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Easier way would be `stringCharacter.toLowerCase().matches("[aeiou]")`